# How do you dynamically recompile a single asset in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

Our application requires assets to be dynamically recompiled. Running rake assets:precompile on a live production server is too expensive. How do I precompile a single asset (this is not an asset that would be bundled).

Comment: Is this in some sort of a CMS type context?

Comment: you can precompile locally and update them on server. this way you can save server resources

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compile assets separated, because this task (rake assets:precompile) stay watching the configs that you set.

This could be a suggestion for rails core team. I have the same problem, with specific css that needed to be compiled alone, without compile another files.